# Numpy switch numbering from columns to rows

Tags: python, numpy

I need to change the numbering scheme of a matrix. Say,

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])
```

And I want to switch it to

```
b = np.array([[0,3],[1,4],[2,5]])
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

So that basically I number the matrix through the rows first. I am sure there is a nice way to do this in numpy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(6).reshape(3,2, order = 'F')
>>> array([[0, 3],
   [1, 4],
   [2, 5]])
```

From the doc:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html

Use order='F' to specify the Fortran traditional representation and order='C' (the default) to use the traditional C representation.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Your final array doesn't match @HansSnah s expected result or the array you created.

Comment: That's just a copy-n-paste error.  I get `a`: `array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
`

Comment: @wwii you're right, that was a copy and paste error, I corrected my reply

Answer (score 2):

To create a view of the same data with the new shape, you can use `a.T.reshape(3, 2, order='F')`:

```
In [35]: a = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)

In [36]: a
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])

In [37]: b = a.T.reshape(3, 2, order='F')

In [38]: b
Out[38]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
```

Verify `a` and `b` are views of the same data, by changing `a` and checking `b`:

```
In [39]: a[1, 0] = 99

In [40]: a
Out[40]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [99,  3],
       [ 4,  5]])

In [41]: b
Out[41]: 
array([[ 0,  3],
       [ 1,  4],
       [99,  5]])
```